# gnuplot x11 and OSX 10.8.2

Tags: osx-lion, gnuplot, x11

I am trying to use gnuplot with OSX 10.8.2, and see x11 is an `ambiguous or unknown terminal type`. A bit of research shows `x11` is not supported, and I download `XQartz`, but I still get the same error message.

I edit .bash_profile with `export GNUTERM = 'x11'` then try `ln -sf /Application/Utilities/XQuartz.app/ X11.app` as suggested [here](http://bl.anthonysutardja.com/post/28024250835/mountain-lion-x11-and-gnuplot)

But still the same error message. 
What else can I try to plot my `gnuplot` files (both on my laptop and from a server)?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you type `xterm` in a terminal window?  I suspect you don't have `x11` installed (or you didn't when gnuplot was built).  Chances are that you need to rebuild gnuplot.  Does gnuplot work with other terminals?  postscript?  aquaterm?

Comment: When I type xterm, x11 opens. I did try to re-configure, make, install gnuplot, and now I am not getting the error, but nothing else happens. No plots. This is true if I try to plot from terminal or from the xterm window.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that setting term to postscript does work. It's x11 that won't.

Comment: Are you trying to make your plot from an interactive prompt or a script?  If you're using a script, what happens if you do `gnuplot -persist myscript`?

Comment: Well, problem solved after re-configuring, making and installing after downloading XQuartz. I was testing plotting to xterm by commenting out a postscript term, but I was using the wrong commenting character. Yep.

Comment: @jgoldst1 could you answer your own question with the solution and then accept it so that the issue gets marked as resolved, please. Just for future purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was resolved by rebuilding Gnuplot after I installed XQuartz.

Comment: If using Homebrew, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22989324/1968462) is the easiest way to do this.