# Octave plotting error

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am new to octave, I just tried my first plotting with Octave 3.4.0 when I get the following error. Any help will be much appreciated. The gnuplot version is 4.6

```
     octave-3.4.0:3> x=1:1:20;
     octave-3.4.0:4> y=sin(x);
     octave-3.4.0:5> plot(x,y)

     gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6"
                  ^
     line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

The terminal window I am using for octave is the mac X-terminal.

Comment: See my complete solution about this problem below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29907389/115363

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to this problem. Just run:

```
setenv("GNUTERM","X11")
```

Before you plot anything, e.g.,

```
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 15):

You might need to reinstall gnuplot with x11 support:

`brew uninstall gnuplot;brew install gnuplot --with-x`

Comment: I found this necessary on OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: Warning: gnuplot: --with-x was deprecated; using --with-x11 instead!

Comment: found this necessary on 10.10.3 as well

Answer (score 13):

Also you could add this line to your ~/.octaverc file:

```
setenv GNUTERM x11
```

- it works for me on mac os mountain lion.

Comment: Where is that directory?

Answer (score 4):

## COMPLETE SOLUTION:

**1- Install x11:**

```
brew cask install xquartz
```

*Or, install from* [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.7.dmg).

**2- Reinstall gnuplot:**

```
brew uninstall gnuplot && brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```

**3- Put these lines in ~/.octaverc**

```
setenv("GNUTERM", "x11")
gnuplot_binary("/usr/local/bin/gnuplot")
```

**4- Restart your mac**

Answer (score 2):

or put this line into your .profile (or .zshrc whatever):

```
export GNUTERM=x11
```

this will make all gunplot invokations (besides Octave) to output to x11.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
setenv ("GNUTERM", "X11")
```

to your octaverc file, normally located at `/usr/local/share/octave/site/m/startup`

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
setenv("GNUTERM", "qt")
```

to the octaverc file located in `/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/startup`, and then it worked again.

Comment: I didn't use brew or macports but used precompiled binaries. And setenv ("GNUTERM", "X11") didn't work. Your solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just put here. When this error happened on me, I found this post and update my octaverc file with "setenv GNUTERM X11".

Then octave generated another error:

```
    error: popen2: popen2 (child): unable to start process -- No such file or directory
    error: called from:
    error: /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/private/__gnuplot_open_stream__.m at line 30, column 40
    error: /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/__gnuplot_drawnow__.m at line 72, column 19
    sh: x11: command not found
```

And the solution to that was adding `gnuplot_binary("usr/YO/bin/gnuplot")` to the octaverc file in `/usr/local/share/octave/site/m/startup`

Now plotting in octave is happy.