# Plot function not working in Octave

Tags: macos, plot, octave, osx-yosemite

I was trying to use **plot(x,y)** function of octave but couldn't use it.

Keep getting this error:

```
warning: function ./test.m shadows a core library function
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

Tried using `setenv("GNUTERM","X11");` before using `plot(x,y)` function, that didn't work.

Saw some couple of stackoverflow and other solutions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166595/octave-plotting-error), [this](http://bits.lot42.com/2013/01/plotting-problems-in-octave-on-mac-os-x/), [this](http://jatinganhotra.com/blog/2014/01/21/installing-octave-on-os-x-10-dot-9-mavericks/) and [this](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-does-not-start-gnuplot-td3058677.html)) but didn't help much.

There wer some site which talks about adding something like this `setenv GNUTERM x11`to append in `.octaverc` file, but unfortunately I don't have `.octaverc`.

```
ikis-MacBook-Pro:Cellar ikis $ find octave -name ".octaverc"
ikis-MacBook-Pro:Cellar ikis $
```

Can any one help with this.

OS: Yosemite

Octave version: GNU Octave, version 4.0.0

Comment: the `.octaverc` does not exist by default. And if it did, it would exist in your home directory, not in the octave installation (it is user configuration). Just create it if you need it. Place it on your home directory if you need it.

Comment: I can't see an error, only to warnings. Can you please add the error message? Have you used hombrew?

Comment: It looks like the error message `warning: function ./test.m shadows a core library function` may be important. Can you edit your question to also show the code in the file test.m?

Comment: Post your reproduction code on https://saturnapi.com so we can all test it